# use specific value from ParseObject to a new query

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to get the value `relatedGuild` from `ParseObject relationShipObject` that has been sent to another method.

My code:

```
private void getRelation(){
    Log.i("Status:", "Retrieving current user...");
    //Retrieve the current logged in user
    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

    Log.i("Status:", "Retrieving relationship...");
    //Retrieve the relationship object for currentUser
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> relationQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("relation");
    query.whereEqualTo("relatedUser", currentUser);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> relationShip, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (ParseObject relationShipObject : relationShip) {
                    // This does not require a network access.
                    relationshipObject.get("relatedGuild");
                    getGuild(relationShipObject);
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("relation", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
private void getGuild(ParseObject relationShipObject){
    Log.d("relation", "relationShipObject:" + relationShipObject.getString("relatedGuild"));
}
```

When i call `Log.d` in method `getGuild` i get a value equal to `null`. Am I trying to retrieve the value from row `relatedGuild` the wrong way? If yes, do you have any solution to the problem?

Update:
When i change from `getString` to `get("relatedGuild").toString()`, i get a value that looks like this: `com.parse.ParseObject@21u702b7`. That means `relationShipObject`contains some kind of value i don't know how to retrieve.

Comment: That means `relatedGuild` is a ParseObject, which indicates that it is a pointer.  So you can get the object from that pointer field by calling `relationShipObject.getParseObject("relatedGuild")`.  Then what you want to do with it is up to you.

Comment: No, getParseObject("relatedGuild") does not fetch the object; only the pointer. To get the object, use include() in the query like I suggest in my answer, or call fetch() on the relatedGuild object before using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void getRelation(){
    Log.i("Status:", "Retrieving current user...");
    //Retrieve the current logged in user
    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

    Log.i("Status:", "Retrieving relationship...");
    //Retrieve the relationship object for currentUser
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> relationQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("relation");
    query.whereEqualTo("relatedUser", currentUser);
    query.include("relatedGuild");  // <-THIS INCLUDES THE OBJECT BEHIND THE POINTER
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> relationShip, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (ParseObject relationShipObject : relationShip) {
                    // This does not require a network access.
                    relationshipObject.get("relatedGuild");
                    getGuild(relationShipObject);
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("relation", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
private void getGuild(ParseObject relationShipObject){
    Log.d("relation", "relationShipObject:" + relationShipObject.getString("relatedGuild"));
}
```